# Выборка и сортировка из 2х таблиц через DISTINCT UNION ORDER BY

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Доброго времени! Есть две одинаковые таблицы mesages и achuvedoms с полями:

```
id (INT 9 (ai)), idl (INT 9), msg (text), date (DATETIME)
```

и мне надо сделать выборку выбрав только строки с уникальным значением idl через DISTINCT при этом рассортировать выборку по полю date и все это из обоих таблиц. Делаю вот так но работает только без сортировки:

```
 $tmp = $db->query("SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM mesages WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."' ORDER BY date DESC
                UNION SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM achuvedoms WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."' ORDER BY date DESC");
```

пробовал так сделать но вообще ничего не работает тогда:

```
 $tmp = $db->query("SELECT * FROM (
                SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM mesages WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
                UNION SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM achuvedoms WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
                ) results ORDER BY date DESC");
```

как можно сделать что бы работало и то и то?

Comment: для сортировки объединения правильным будет второй вариант, а не работает он , потому что вы во внешний запрос не выбираете дату, по которой хотите сортировать.

Comment: @teran простите, во внешний это в плане вместо звездочки перечислить? $tmp = $db->query("SELECT id,idl,date FROM (
     SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM mesages WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
     UNION SELECT DISTINCT idl FROM achuvedoms WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
     ) results ORDER BY date DESC"); но так у меня тоже не хочет работать\

Comment: у вас в `results` нет даты, чтобы сортировать по ней, у вас туда выбираются только `select distinct idl`, а нужны `idl, date` чтобы было по чему сортировку делать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Второй запрос верен, но подзапрос должен содержать все поля, к которым идет обращение из внешнего запроса

```
SELECT distinct idl FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT idl, date FROM mesages WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
  UNION 
  SELECT DISTINCT idl, date FROM achuvedoms WHERE ida='".$getuser['id']."'
) results ORDER BY date DESC
```